# VS2008 Keyboard shortcut Ctrl + . stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

The new awesome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show smart tags has suddenly stopped working, a week or so after I discovered it :(

I am missing it badly, having had to revert back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, which really just isn't the same.

I recently installed F# CTP 1.9.6.2

Has anyone else

- installed this CTP and still has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
- Lost <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> without installing F#
- Even better, found how to get it back again?

**EDIT** In attempting John Sheehan recommendation, I have noticed that my available mapping schemes only include `Visual C# 2005`, should I not have a 2008?

Also the mapped shortcut to this is

```
OtherContextMenus.FSIConsoleContext.CancelEvaluation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just discovered this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2008/09/17/f-september-2008-ctp-known-issues.aspx) that references the problem.

I have just tested it and it works!

Cheers John Sheehan for at least getting me to a step that gave me some googleable terms, I have given you an upmod as a thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the keyboard mappings to see if there's another one conflicting with it. 'Tools > Options > Keyboard' type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> in the 'Press shortcut keys' box and see what comes up in the 'Shortcut currently used by' box. If there's more than one, just remove the conflicting one. You want it to be assigned to `View.ShowSmartTag`.

Or maybe just reset your keyboard settings.